# How to write apk of an app to a folder

Tags: java, android, apk

I am trying to get the APK of an app and save it in a folder on storage directory. I have got the apk but I am not able to save it to my desired folder.

**Here is how I am generating apk file:**

```
    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> apps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo info : apps) {
            File fileToSave = new File(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir)
    }
```

**Here is the code to Save the APK file where I am passing the same file to save:**

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(File fileToSave) {
        try {
            String folderName = "MyCreatedFolder";

            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                    File.separator + folderName);
            boolean success = true;
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                success = folder.mkdirs();
            }
            if (success) {
                File path = new File(context.getFilesDir(), folderName);
                File mypath = new File(path, fileToSave.getName());
                new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(mypath));
                Toast.makeText(context, "Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("----" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

The fileToSave is the APK file but writing it says no such file or directory.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..../MyCreatedFolder/base.apk: open
>   failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

**All the required permissions are there and runtime permissions not required as TargetSDK is 21.**

How to save this file to my storage directory.?

Comment: Have you mentioned the required permissions in your manifest file? Also, starting from Android M, you need to implement run-time permissions.

Comment: Yes I have added the permissions, and runtime permissions not required as TargetSDK is 21. Updated question with same info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code because you want to create a folder (if it does not exist),then write into the same exact folder you created/specified hence the omission of this line  `File path = new File(context.getFilesDir(), folderName);`    but instead the path of the folder we created.

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(File fileToSave) {
    try {
        String folderName = "MyCreatedFolder";
        String dire = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File dir = new File(dire +"/"+ folderName);
        boolean success = true;
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            success=dir.mkdirs();
        }

        if (success) {
            File mypath = new File(dir + "/"+folderName+"/", fileToSave.getName());               
            new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(mypath));
            Toast.makeText(context, "Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("----" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should OP try your code? Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: No not working. Is it possible that I am generating apk in wrong way.? I have updated the question how I am generating apk file.

Comment: Check if the file to save is null